# How to order entries in ipywidgets Dropdown or Select?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to select from a list of possible values of type float:

```
values = [400e-9,435e-9,498e-9]
```

The ipywidgets module provides the Select and Dropdown widgets, which accept either a list of strings, or a dictionary. In the latter case, the keys will be displayed and the values will be used when the corresponding key is selected. See [the list of widgets in the docs](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Widget%20List.ipynb).

```
# Required imports for examples below
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
```

Indeed, supplying my list of values directly raises an error since the values are floats, not strings.

```
# This will raise a TraitError
w = widgets.Select(options=values,description='Select one of the values:')
display(w)
```

So I create a dictionary and pass this to the widget:

```
keys = ["{:.2e}".format(val) for val in values]
valsdict = dict(zip(keys,values))
w = widgets.Select(options=valsdict, description='Select one of the values:')
display(w)
```

However, since dictionaries are not sorted, the resulting widget shows the options in a seemingly random order. In this case, when I ran it, 498e-9 came before 435e-9, as shown in this screenshot: [screenshot of the resulting widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcIlF.jpg).

So the question is, is there a way to sort the entries in the selection widgets?

An obvious workaround is to supply the widget only with my list of strings (called `keys` in the example above) and implement looking up the corresponding value from the list myself, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you considered using a sorted dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a tuple list:

```
vals = list(zip(keys,values))
w = widgets.Select(options=vals, description='Select one of the values:')
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more options to consider:

1. Map values from floats to strings:

   ```
   w = widgets.Select(options=map(str,values), description='Select one of the values:')
   ```

   This is in my opinion much more idiomatic then creating a dictionary with strings of the values as keys. It is also much shorter :).
2. Use an ordered dict:

   ```
   from collections import OrderedDict
   names = map(str,values)
   od_vals = OrderedDict(zip(names,values))
   w = widgets.Select(options=od_vals, description='Select one of the values:')
   ```

   The advantage here is that the list `names` can be anything you want, e.g. `names=['choice 1','choice 2','choice 3']`. This then allows you to get the value selected by `od_vals[w.selected_label]` which is not possible for method 1 or your accepted answer.